# Create real-time MySQL parser to MongoDB php

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

Right now I do some project to make normal MySQL syntax in PHP can work with MongoDB. 
I already done in some simple `syntax(SELECT, CREATE)` by create my own PHP library for user to pass their MySQL syntax to my function(Ex. `MongoQuery("SELECT User FROM A=1"))`, it will parser MySQL to Mongo Syntax and also query data from MongoDB.

But my question is, have any possible ways to make php can capture SQL syntax real-time when web is running?

For example, user not need to edit any code in their PHP file, just simple put it in web server folder and my program will handle to change MySQL operation to MongoDB operation and also query data from MongoDB return to normal SQL return value variable. Thank you :)

Comment: I do not think you can "sniff" the queries launched in real time without having your code included on those pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can not just change those things in the fly, unless you write a PHP extension.

It is also never a good thing to use a document database like MongoDB as it were a relational database like MySQL. They have totally different features and performance characteristics. For example, MongoDB does not have joins, but instead uses embedded or nested documents; MongoDB does not do transactions either, so you will need to do things in another atomic way; MongoDB also does not do "WHERE A=B", so you need to redo your query thoughts.

In short, transparently converting SQL DQL to MongoDB queries is not possible.